# Does Groovy YamlSlurper support anchors and aliases?

Tags: groovy, yaml

It seems to me that groovy YamlSlurper simply discards anchors and does not resolve aliases.

I have the example taken from yaml spec that I parse using the YamlSlurper.

```
def ys = new YamlSlurper()
def yaml = ys.parseText $/
---
hr:
- Mark McGwire
# Following node labeled SS
- &SS Sammy Sosa
rbi:
- *SS # Subsequent occurrence
- Ken Griffey
/$
println yaml
```

The output is

```
[hr:[Mark McGwire, Sammy Sosa], rbi:[SS, Ken Griffey]]
```

It should be

```
[hr:[Mark McGwire, Sammy Sosa], rbi:[Sammy Sosa, Ken Griffey]]
```

Internally groovy uses com.fasterxml.jackson to convert yaml into json.
And then it puts everything into maps.
And Jackson says that it is using SnakeYaml which should support anchors and aliases.
But somewhere there is a disconnect.

So is it really so that in groovy yaml the anchors and aliases are not supported?

Comment: unfortunately groovy is using fasterxml to parse yaml and there is an open issue: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/issues/98